# How can I use unicode characters in HTML keywords?

Tags: html, unicode, character, meta-tags, keyword

The meta section of HTML documents can contain a keyword section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="under construction" />
        <meta name="keywords"
          content="..." />
```

Can one use unicode characters in this section (i.e., `\u00B0`)? If yes how?

Comment: On a side note, `<!DOCTYPE html>` is an HTML5 doctype. The preferred HTML5 way to declare the document's charset is to use `<meta charset="...">` instead of `<meta http-equiv="text/html; charset=...">`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the characters you put into an HTML document, whether in attribute values or elsewhere, as Unicode characters. If the character encoding of your document is UTF-8, as your example declares (but it had better be UTF-8 encoded then!), you can enter any characters, such as the degree sign (°), directly there. How you do that depends on your authoring environment. You can alternatively use a character reference (`like &#xb0;`) or, for some characters, an entity reference (`like &deg;`).

But \u00B0 is not an HTML notation. It just a sequence of six characters. It has a special meaning in JavaScript, but not in HTML. The corresponding HTML notation is `&#xb0;`.

Search engines will probably ignore special characters like the degree sign in keywords. But not necessarily; Google has been observed to be sensitive to them in some special situations. (Not for the degree sign at the moment, it seems.)

In `<meta name=description ...>` tags, special characters may be relevant if search engines use their content when constructing the page description for search result lists. Such things still happen, though less frequently than they used to.

Answer (score 3):

Because non-English websites that use Unicode for their body content will also use Unicode for their metadata, it is reasonable to assume that the important tools that process HTML metadata will be able to cope with this in UTF-8.

Also bear in mind that (at least historically) the `keywords` meta tag was meant to contain terms that people might search for. Your example `\00B0` is the degrees sign; in this case it seems more likely people will search for the word *degrees* than for the symbol °. Because of wide-scale abuse of keyword metadata, many search engines (including [Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)) ignore them for search ranking.

So, in summary, **I think it is safe to use Unicode keyword metadata. But it probably won't improve your site's search ranking for those terms**.

Comment: That advice from the W3C is focused on control codes and the like, not standard printable characters.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. I agree and have edited my answer to remove that part. I think the rest still holds.